# Somar dados dentro de um dataframe baseado em uma condição para duas colunas

Tags: python, pandas

Eu tenho um DF com quatro colunas. Preciso somar os valores da coluna 3 quando os valores da coluna 1 e 2 são duplicados e descartar as duplicatas. Ex:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,1,1,1,2,2],
                   "B": [4,4,5,5,6,6],
                    "C" : [1,2,3,4,5,6]})
```

Precisaria somar os valores da coluna C quando o par de valores de A e B é duplicado. Ficando com:

```
Df_resultante:
       A  B  C
       1  4  3
       1  5  7
       2  6  11
```

Answer (score 0):

Se sempre tem essa estrutura, você pode simplesmente usar `groupby`:

```
df.groupby(['A','B']).agg({'C':'sum'}).reset_index()
```

Comment: E se tiver uma quarta coluna que eu preciso manter os valores máximos no df resultante? Funciona se dentro do aggregate eu colocar: agg({'C':'sum','D':'max'})?

Comment: sim. Funciona sim. Pode passar uma função do numpy tbm como `np.max`

Comment: Na estrutura passada, bastaria `df.groupby(['A','B']).sum().reset_index()` que é mais rápido que o `agg`